# How do you refer to arrays within arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

If I did this:

```
<?php
$array = array();
$array['bar'] = "bar";
$array['foo'] = array();
?>
```

How do I add values into the $array['foo'] array? (but not like add another array into that just keys and values)

Answer (score 4):

```
$array['foo']['blah'] = 'asdf';
```

Comment: Or just `$array['foo'][] = 'asdf';` if you didn't care about the index value.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$array = array();
$array['bar'] = 'bar';
$array['foo'] = array();

$array['foo']['key'] = 'var'; // if you want it to be hash table
or
$array['foo'][] = 'var'; // generates the index for you.
?>
```

Then if you want to access that thing:

```
<?php echo $array['foo']['key']; ?>
```

Or if you used the [] way:

```
<?php echo $array['foo'][0]; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array['foo']['x'] = 'something';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array['foo'][] = $your_value_to_insert;
```

Answer (score 0):

like @cyclone and:

```
$array['foo'] = array("foo" => "bar", 12 => true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$array['foo'] = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'abc');
```